# SQL - selecting all rows with maximum value

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS price
FROM (SELECT * FROM rt WHERE somecondition) AS st
      JOIN tt
      ON st.id = tt.id
GROUP BY id;
```

Now, I want to select all rows which have the maximum price of the table. I have tried this, which unfortunately returns no row at all:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS price
FROM (SELECT * FROM rt WHERE somecondition) AS st
      JOIN tt
      ON st.id = tt.id
GROUP BY id
HAVING price = MAX(price);
```

I'm somewhat lost, does anybody have any pointers?

Comment: I doubt if `HAVING` can be used that way

Comment: And which is the maximum price of the table? At least should be just 1 max price, so you will have 1 row

Comment: @albanx That's what I thought, too.

Comment: Also `GROUP BY id ` is not needed, id should be unique and the `JOIN` does it for you.

Comment: @Dan Yes, the price is equals to the number of occurences of that ID. It's not the same for all IDs.

Comment: You are also missing the join table

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 4):

This looks fairly simple to me:

```
select * from <table> 
where <column name> in(
   SELECT MAX(column name) FROM table
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT a.id, a.price
FROM
(
    SELECT aa.id, COUNT(1) AS price
    FROM rt aa
    INNER JOIN tt bb ON aa.id = bb.id
    WHERE aa.somecondition
    GROUP BY aa.id
) a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(aa.price) AS maxprice
    FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS price
        FROM rt aaa
        INNER JOIN tt bbb ON aaa.id = bbb.id
        WHERE aaa.somecondition
        GROUP BY aaa.id
    ) aa
) b ON a.price = b.maxprice
```

**Edit**: While I can't think of any way to rewrite this so as to not have to write the base-queries redundantly, what you ***could*** perhaps do is this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.id) AS ids, a.price
FROM
(
    SELECT aa.id, COUNT(1) AS price
    FROM rt aa
    INNER JOIN tt bb ON aa.id = bb.id
    WHERE aa.somecondition
    GROUP BY aa.id
) a
GROUP BY a.price
ORDER BY a.price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This produces a comma-separated-list of the ids that share the same maximum value. This is probably not the format you are looking for though, but it ***is*** one way to avoid having to write the base-query twice. Just putting that out there.

Comment: It's a matter of preference I suppose, but I used your version as a template. I'm voting for you.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to write parts of the query redundantly. Is there any way around it?

Comment: @ryyst, I'm afraid there is no way around it. This is the most efficient solution I know of that actually works in MySQL. The important thing to note is that I'm using strictly joins for subselects which execute only once as opposed to `WHERE` or `HAVING` subqueries that execute for each row. @shawnt00's solution would be nice if MySQL supported CTE's, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` is used to check conditions after the aggregation takes place.

`WHERE` is used before the aggregation takes place.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS price
FROM (SELECT * FROM rt WHERE somecondition) AS st
  JOIN tt
  ON st.id = tt.id
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM ...table)
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: `WHERE price = MAX(price)` never works. `max()` is a single-value function that can not directly be used in the `WHERE` clause of SQL.

Comment: It's used in a subquery. That's perfectly fine.

Comment: The problem is that price is only defined in the outermost `SELECT` statement, so when writing `SELECT MAX(price) FROM ...table`, I would need a name for that table.

Comment: @ryyst, I was referring to the concept of using a subquery. Your arrangement here is a bit unusual. Could you elaborate on the reason that price is defined by counting rows?

Comment: Well, imagine a table where items are associated with individual coins. So if an item is associated with 10 coins, it has the price 10.  The situation is a bit more complex, but that's the general idea.

Comment: These queries are little to be inefficient if you're not careful. Creating a name for the value is easy to accomplish by wrapping the query with another SELECT. You'll also notice that my answer works around the need to refer to max price by name.

Answer (score 0):

try this, put MAX in select, this should be the correct way

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS price, MAX(price) AS max_price
FROM (SELECT some_table_name FROM rt WHERE somecondition LIMIT 1) AS st
      JOIN thenextTable as tt
      ON st.id = tt.id
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: It says "unknown column 'price' in field list".

Comment: This query `SELECT * FROM rt WHERE somecondition` should return a table name. verify that this table has the column price?

Comment: @ryyst:) Try using `MAX(st.price)`.

Comment: And it should be `SELECT some_table_name FROM rt WHERE somecondition LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that @Zane's answer is what you do want, here's a portable version of his query that also avoids LIMIT/TOP operations. I'm not really familiar with mysql dialects, but I imagine this will work without problem.

```
SELECT a.id, a.price
FROM (
    SELECT aa.id, COUNT(1) AS price
    FROM rt aa
    INNER JOIN tt bb ON aa.id = bb.id
    WHERE [somecondition]
    GROUP BY aa.id
) a
WHERE
    a.price >= ALL (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS maxprice
        FROM rt aa
        INNER JOIN tt bb ON aa.id = bb.id
        WHERE [somecondition]
        GROUP BY aa.id
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for an approach that didn't require the redundancy of stating the inner query more than once. That's certainly what a cte is good for. These are two other solutions rewritten to use that tactic.

```
WITH basequery as (
    SELECT aa.id, COUNT(1) AS price
    FROM rt aa INNER JOIN tt bb ON aa.id = bb.id
    WHERE [aa.somecondition]
    GROUP BY aa.id
)
SELECT a.id, a.price
FROM
    basequery as a INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(price) AS maxprice FROM basequery) as b
        ON a.price = b.maxprice
-- or
WITH basequery as (
    SELECT aa.id, COUNT(1) AS price
    FROM rt aa INNER JOIN tt bb ON aa.id = bb.id
    WHERE [aa.somecondition]
    GROUP BY aa.id
)
SELECT a.id, a.price
FROM
    basequery as a
WHERE
    a.price >= ALL (SELECT price FROM basequery)
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm learning more about CTE's everyday. This would be awesome if only MySQL supported it. =(